# MarkLogic diacritic-insensitive snippet

Tags: search, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, search-snippet

For now I'm using this code to generate snippet, based on a JSON document that I'm getting from MarkLogic search.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace searchlib="http://ihs.com/lib/searchlib";
import module namespace search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy"; 
import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

declare function searchlib:get-snippet($docc,$words) {
  let $doc:= json:transform-from-json($docc)
  let $squery := search:parse($words)
  let $result := <result>{search:snippet($doc,$squery,
  <transform-results apply="snippet" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
          <max-snippet-chars>255</max-snippet-chars>

      </transform-results>)}</result>

  return $result//search:match
};
```

When performing search I'm using:

```
cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery(fieldname, values, 
                                             ['case-insensitive', 'diacritic-insensitive'])
```

So search works diacritic-insensitive and produces good results, but in `search:snippet` I'm not able to pass `diacritic-insensitive` option as in `cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery`.

In [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/search:snippet) I can see this in description

> Options to define the search grammar and control the search. See description for $options for the function search:search. Note that you cannot specify the apply attribute on the transform-results option with search:snippet; to use a different snippetting function, use search:search or search:resolve instead.

But in here it is:

```
search:snippet(
   $result as node(),
   $cts-query as schema-element(cts:query),
   [$options as element(search:transform-results)?]
) as element(search:snippet)
```

So does it mean I can't pass other options to search:snippet? Or is there a option to do this?

I'm testing it using `chávez` and it is producing results, but snippets are generated properly only for documents containing exact match that means that document

> Chavez did something

Will not get highligh on `Chavez` and

> Chávez did something

Will get a highligh

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you mean that the `<search:highlight>Chavez</search:highlight>` is not part of the result. This may very well be a bug with MarkLogic, as it seems contrary to what one might expect from this function. As a workaround, you could consider writing a function that adds the highlighting post-process, though doing so may not be trivial (consider using NFD (decomposition), which makes it trivial to remove diacritics on both search term and result, and search within result using normal XPath/XQuery functions).

Comment: @Abel yeah that's exactly my problem. I didn't get highlight on `Chavez`. I'm afraid that doing it manually can decrease performance, but maybe I'll try making some functions that parses documents. Thanks!

Comment: You should also consider letting MarkLogic know, if it's a bug, maybe they already have a workaround, or even a patch.

Comment: @Abel I have posted a ticket to MarkLogic :)

Comment: If they answer with either a workaround, a solution or a "sorry, it is not a feature that will be considered", can you answer your own question with it?

Comment: @Abel I'll post an answer from MarkLogic

Comment: @Abel got answer from MarkLogic, posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in not passing options to `search:snippet`, but to `search:parse`

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace searchlib="http://ihs.com/lib/searchlib";
import module namespace search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy"; 
import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

declare function searchlib:get-snippet($docc,$words) {
  let $doc:= json:transform-from-json($docc)
  let $squery := search:parse($words,
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<term>
<term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
<term-option>diacritic-insensitive</term-option>
</term>
</options>, "cts:query")

  let $result := <result>{search:snippet($doc,$squery,
  <transform-results apply="snippet" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
          <max-snippet-chars>255</max-snippet-chars>

      </transform-results>)}</result>

  return $result//search:match
};
```

passing

```
<term-option>diacritic-insensitive</term-option>
```

to `search:parse` made it work.

Here is explanation from MarkLogic:

> The `search:snippet()` function allows you to extract matching text and
>   returns the matches wrapped in a containing node, with highlights
>   tagged. However, to allow the search:snippet to extract the correct
>   text, the `cts:query()` that is passed to the snippet should match the
>   sequence of values. For `search:snippet`, `cts:query` is typically a
>   result of a call to `search:parse`. The `search:parse()` function parses
>   query text according to given options and returns the appropriate
>   `cts:query` XML.